# MS SQL: What is the easiest/nicest way to create a linked server with SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner with SQL so I struggle with the MSDN description for creating a linked server in Management Studio.

I whant to link a SQL Server into another to use everything from ServerB on ServerA to e.g. provide one location other systems can connect to.

Both servers are in the same domain and both server have several databases inside.

When I start creating a linked server on ServerA in the general tap I select a name for the linked server and select SQL Server as Server type.
But I struggle on the Security tap. I have on both servers sa privilege so what is to set here? 
Or which role should I take/crate for this connection?

My plan is to create views in a certain DB on ServerA with has also content of ServerB inside.
This views will be conusumed from an certain AD service user.
I already added this service user to the security on ServerA where the views are stored.
Do I also have to add this user somewhere on the linked ServerB?

Comment: Are you using Windows Integrated Security for authentication or do you login to your servers using the SQL server sa account?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot this detail! Yes we use Windows Integrated Security.

Comment: My plan is to create views in a certain DB on ServerA with has also content of ServerB inside.
This views will be conusumed from an certain AD service user.
I already added this service user to the security on ServerA where the views are stored.
Do I also have to add this user somewhere on the linked ServerB?

Comment: You might be able to find some useful questions/answers on [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=linked+server+security) StackExchange as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Server Objects => right click New Linked Server

[image]

**2.** The “New Linked Server” Dialog appears.  (see below).[image]

**3.** For “Server Type” make sure “Other Data Source” is selected.  (The
    SQL Server option will force you to specify the literal SQL Server
    Name)

- Type in a friendly name that describes your linked server (without spaces). – Select “Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server”
- Product Name – type: SQLSERVER (with no spaces)
- Datasource – type the actual server name, and instance name using this convention: SERVERNAMEINSTANCENAME
- ProviderString – Blank
- Catalog – Optional (If entered use the default database you will be using)
- Prior to exiting, continue to the next section (defining security)
  [image]
- Click OK, and the new linked server is created

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use Windows Authentication. Activate [Security Delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189580.aspx).

In the Security tab, choose "Add". Select your Windows user and check "Impersonate".

As a quick and dirty solution, you can choose "Be made using this security context" from the options list and enter a SQL Login which is valid on the remote server. Since quick and dirty solutions tend to last, i would strongly recommend to spend some time on impersonation.

Comment: I do not whant a dirty solution! I like to have the correct and clean solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to specify to make the connection using the current context, i.e. the user loging on to ServerA:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ServerB', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'ServerB',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
```

This however assumes that users accessing the linked server connection have the correct privileges on ServerB (part 2 of your question) - otherwise you'd need to use impersonation as described by Martin K.